# Reference request for a complete and formal Duality Principle in category theory

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, lo.logic, duality

Most textbooks on category theory only sketch the meaning of the Duality Principle. But even when they do it more formally, I have only seen a version so far which concerns the language of a (single) category, see for example [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Duality_Principle_(Category_Theory)) or Remark 3.7 in [The Joy of Cats](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/The+Joy+of+Cats) or Rem. 3.6.18 in my book. This can be applied to very basic statements such as

- "Any two initial objects are uniquely isomorphic" $\stackrel{~~\text{op}~~}{\leadsto}$ "any two terminal objects are uniquely isomorphic"

But we certainly want to and actually do apply the Duality Principle also in more complicated situations with sets of categories and functors between them, perhaps even more data. Here are some common examples.

- "Any faithful functor reflects monomorphisms" $\stackrel{~~\text{op}~~}{\leadsto}$ "Any faithful functor reflects epimorphisms"
- "The product of a family of complete categories is complete"  $\stackrel{~~\text{op}~~}{\leadsto}$ "The product of a family of cocomplete categories is cocomplete"
- "For functors into a complete category, right Kan extensions exist."  $\stackrel{~~\text{op}~~}{\leadsto}$ "For functors into a cocomplete category, left Kan extensions exist."
- "The left adjoint of a functor is unique up to isomorphism."  $\stackrel{~~\text{op}~~}{\leadsto}$ "The right adjoint of a functor is unique up to isomorphism."
- "A category with finite products admits a monoidal structure with $\otimes = \times$"  $\stackrel{~~\text{op}~~}{\leadsto}$ "A category with finite coproducts admits a monoidal structure with $\otimes = \sqcup$"
- "The category of monoids in a cocomplete monoidal category* is cocomplete"  $\stackrel{~~\text{op}~~}{\leadsto}$ "The category of comonoids in a complete monoidal category* is complete". (*This means in particular that $\otimes$ is (co)continuous in each variable.)
- "If $T$ is a monad on a category $\mathcal{C}$, then the forgetful functor $\mathrm{Alg}(T) \to \mathcal{C}$ creates limits"  $\stackrel{~~\text{op}~~}{\leadsto}$ "If $T$ is a comonad on a category $\mathcal{C}$, then  the forgetful functor $\mathrm{CoAlg}(T) \to \mathcal{C}$ creates colimits"

I assume that we have to find a language $\mathcal{L}$ which contains the language of a category, and the Duality Principle then states that a bunch of data $D$ satisfies a statement $\varphi$ iff the "dualized data" $D^{\mathrm{op}}$ satisfies the "dual statement" $\varphi^{\mathrm{op}}$. I assume that the proof will be a trivial induction, once we have formalized everything. This looks like a doable task. But I don't want to reinvent the wheel here.

**Question.** Where does such a formal Duality Principle appear in the literature? In particular, it is required that all of the examples mentioned above should immediately follow from it.

In case it doesn't appear in the literature, answers are welcome which themselves state such a formal Duality Principle.

Here is an answer if we only want to include the first statement: The *language of a functor* has two copies of the language of a category (so we have four sorts $\mathrm{Ob}(C_1),\mathrm{Ob}(C_2),\mathrm{Mor}(C_1),\mathrm{Mor}(C_2)$, maps $\mathrm{cod}_{C_i} : \mathrm{Mor}(C_i) \to \mathrm{Ob}(C_i)$ etc.) as well as two function symbols $\mathrm{Ob}(F) : \mathrm{Ob}(C_1) \to \mathrm{Ob}(C_2)$, $\mathrm{Mor}(F) : \mathrm{Mor}(C_1) \to \mathrm{Mor}(C_2)$. The *theory of a functor* consists of the (formalized) category axioms for $C_1$, $C_2$ as well as the (formalized) functor axioms for $F$ (so $\mathrm{cod}_{C_2}(\mathrm{Mor}(F)(f))=\mathrm{Ob}(F)(\mathrm{cod}_{C_1}(f))$ etc.). By construction, any functor between two small categories provides a model of the theory. If $\varphi$ is any formula in the language of a functor, then $\varphi^{\mathrm{op}}$ is defined recursively: any occurence of $\mathrm{cod}_{C_i}$ is replaced by $\mathrm{dom}_{C_i}$ etc. Now the Duality Principle states that a functor $F : \mathcal{C}_1 \to \mathcal{C}_2$ satisfies a statement $\varphi$ (which may also contain some parameters) iff $F^{\mathrm{op}} : \mathcal{C}_1^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathcal{C}_2^{\mathrm{op}}$ satisfies $\varphi^{\mathrm{op}}$. In this language there there are sentences $\phi,\psi$ whose models are faithful functors resp. functors which preserve monomorphisms. Thus, if we can prove that $\phi \Rightarrow \psi$ is true (faithful functors preserve monos), it follows that $(\phi \Rightarrow \psi)^{\mathrm{op}} = \phi^{\mathrm{op}} \Rightarrow \psi^{\mathrm{op}}$ is true as well (faithful functors preserve epis).

The question appeared while working on another edition of my book. The treatment of the duality principle there is rather sloppy, and a more formal and complete statement (not necessarily including a proof) would be very nice.

Comment: What do you imagine this duality theorem could say, other than a bureaucratic version of what we know? If you have a valid statement beginning "any category" then that is a free variable, for which you may substitute the opposite applied to "any category". Then "opposite" commutes with the other features of category theory in the way we all know.

Comment: I don't understand your question, unfortunately. Have you read my question actually and checked out the links in the 1st paragraph?

Comment: More generally, a formal duality principle could be stated for any 2-category with a duality involution. However, the induction is so trivial I'd be surprised if anyone has written it out explicitly. The one place I could imagine it having been done is in a formalisation of category theory, such as in a category theory library for a proof assistant (e.g. [UniMath](https://github.com/UniMath/UniMath), or [HoTT-Agda](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT-Agda)); perhaps it'd be worth taking a look at some of these.

Comment: I believe all the statements you've listed follow from the theorem that $(-)^{op} : CAT \to CAT$ is an automorphism of the category of categories. In general, if you have an automorphism of a (first-order, say) structure (such as $CAT$, viewed as a structure in your favorite language for categories), then pushing forward along the automorphism converts true sentences into true sentences. To make this precise, I suppose you need to say something about how you're treating size, but any reasonable treatment will work the same way.

Comment: @TimCampion Thanks! However, we need an automorphism of the 2-category of categories - in particular to talk about adjunctions.

Comment: $CAT$ is cartesian closed: the 2-categorical structure is definable in terms of the 1-categorical structure. So any automorphism of the 1-category $CAT$ is also a 2-categorical automorphism.

Comment: @TimCampion I don't think that's quite right, I think you get an automorphism between the 2-category structure you start with and one defined via the automorphism - at least op ought to give an equivalence between CAT = 2-cat of cats and CAT^{2-op} (reversing 2-morphisms)

Comment: @TimCampion Your proposal that all the statements follow from op being an automorphism of Cat just shifts the problem to the question: find a formal language of statements about Cat which are invariant under an automorphism of Cat. That's quite similar to the problem of finding a formal duality principle. Also, it isn't necessarily the case that all of category can be expressed in the *category* Cat (or even the *2-category* Cat). For instance, when is a morphism in Cat fully faithful and when is an object in Cat cocomplete? Maybe you can encode much à la Lawvere, but not necessarily everythi.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Can you elaborate on your comment?